# Free gap time between two employers for expat in the Netherlands

Tags: working-visas, resident-permit, netherlands, legal

I’m an expat in the Netherlands and staying here as a high skill immigrant. Today I received a mail from IND (Immigration department), which saying that I must take action, otherwise they will revoke my permit.

This problem caused by I had a gap time of 18 days, between the time I terminated the working contract with my old company and before starting contract with the new company, and somehow this violated their rules.

Before I made this decision, I already called them to ask if it is allowed to do it or not, they said it is totally fine, now they put me to problem because of some rule, condition I never heard before. And even not in english.

They asked for evidence to against their action. My question is does anyone here have this problem before and how you solve it?

Comment: What is "They asked for evidence to against their action"? What is the action you "must take". Did they ask for specific information? Please [edit] your question and be **specific**. "Somehow this violated their rules" suggests that you do not know what rule, so the first thing to do is contact them and ask specifically what is 'wrong' or missing. Especially because you asked earlier. You cannot claim their earlier answer as approval, but you should say are just unclear about what *exactly* is going on.

Comment: What happened in the end?

Comment: OP, can you describe what happened eventually?